# How can I run create Dataproc cluster, run job, delete cluster from Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I would like to start a Dataproc job in response to log files arriving in GCS bucket. I also do not want to keep a persistent cluster running as new log files arrive only several times a day and it would be idle most of the time.

Answer (score 3):

**A newer version of this tutorial is available here**: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/workflow-function

I can use [WorkflowTemplate API](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/projects.locations.workflowTemplates) to manage the cluster lifecycle for me. With Dataproc Workflows I don't have to poll for either cluster to be created, or job created, or do any error handling.

Here's my Cloud Function. Set to `Cloud Storage bucket` to trigger on `Finalize/Create` event:

**index.js:**

```
exports.startWorkflow = (event, callback) => {

  const {
    google
  } = require('googleapis');

  const region = 'global'
  const zone = 'us-central1-a'
  const clusterName = 'my-cluster'

  const file = event.data;
  console.log("Event: ", file);

  if (!file.name) {
    throw "Skipped processing file!";
  }

  const queryFileUri = "gs://" + file.bucket + "/" + file.name

  console.log("Creating auth client: ");
  google.auth.getApplicationDefault(
    (err, authClient, projectId) => {
      if (authClient.createScopedRequired && authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
        authClient = authClient.createScoped([
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
        ]);
      }

      const request = {
        parent: "projects/" + projectId + "/regions/" + region,
        resource: {
          "placement": {
            "managedCluster": {
              "clusterName": clusterName,
              "config": {
                "gceClusterConfig": {
                  "zoneUri": zone, // Can be omitted if using regional endpoint (like us-central1-a, not global)
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "jobs": [{
            "stepId": "step1",
            "pigJob": {
              "queryFileUri": queryFileUri,
            },
            "prerequisiteStepIds": [],
          }]
        }
      };

      const dataproc = google.dataproc({
        version: 'v1beta2',
        auth: authClient
      });
      dataproc.projects.regions.workflowTemplates.instantiateInline(
        request, (err, result) => {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          }
          console.log(result);
          callback();
        });
    });
};
```

Make sure to set Function to Execute to `startWorkflow`.

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "dataproc-workflow",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies":{ "googleapis": "30.0.0"}
}
```

Comment: will this create a new job every time?

Answer (score -1):

You can put below GCLOUD commands from a shell script or Docker RUN command to:

1. Provision a Dataproc cluster
2. Execute a Spark Job
3. Delete the Dataproc Cluster (note the --quite or -q option to delete)

   ## Provision Dataproc Cluster: (takes 5+ mins)

   gcloud dataproc clusters create devops-poc-dataproc-cluster --subnet default --zone us-central1-a --master-machine-type n1-standard-1 --master-boot-disk-size 200 --num-workers 2 --worker-machine-type n1-standard-2 --worker-boot-disk-size 200 --image-version 1.3-deb9 --project gcp-project-212501 --service-account=service-id1@gcp-project-212501.iam.gserviceaccount.com

   ## Submit the Spark job:

   sleep 60 && gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark /dev_app/spark_poc/wordCountSpark.py --cluster=devops-poc-dataproc-cluster -- gs://gcp-project-212501-docker_bucket/input/ gs://gcp-project-212501-docker_bucket/output/

   ## DELETE Dataproc Cluster:

   gcloud dataproc clusters delete -q devops-poc-dataproc-cluster