# Google Cloud Storage JSONs to Pandas Dataframe to Warehouse

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, etl, data-warehouse

I am a newbie in ETL. I just managed to extract a lot of information in form of JSONs to GCS. Each JSON file includes identical key-value pairs and now I would like to transform them into dataframes on the basis of certain key values.

The next step would be loading this into a data warehouse like Clickhouse, I guess? I was not able to find any tutorials on this process.
TLDR 1) Is there a way to transform JSON data on GCS in Python without downloading the whole data?
TLDR 2) How can I set this up to run periodically or in real time?
TLDR 3) How can I go about loading the data into a warehouse?

If these are too much, I would love it if you can point me to resources around this. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to do this.

1. You can add files to storage, then a `Cloud Functions` is activated every time a new file is added (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) and will call an endpoint in `Cloud Run` (container service - https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/building/containers) running a `Python` application to transform these `JSONs` in a `dataframe`. Note that the container image will be stored in `Container Registry`. Then the Python notebook running on Cloud Run will save the rows incrementally to `BigQuery` (warehouse). After that you can have analytics with `Looker Studio`.
2. If you need to scale the solution to millions/billions of rows, you can add files to storage, `Cloud Functions` is activated and calls `Dataproc`, a service where you can run Python, `Anaconda`, etc. ([How to call google dataproc job from google cloud function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259301/how-to-call-google-dataproc-job-from-google-cloud-function)). Then this `Dataproc` cluster will structurate the JSONs as a dataframe and save to the warehouse (BigQuery).

Comment: We need a very much scalable service, yes. I have not experience with Dataproc but will give it a go, thank you.